# How to Pass Textbox value to SQLDataSource and Fire MessageBox based on Query Result?

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource

I've created a simple form that contains a textbox prompting the user to enter an ID.  There's a submit button on the form and a SQLDataSource that wires up the textbox value as a parameter for the query.

```
<fieldset>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAcctNo">Please enter the account number:</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAcctNo"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" />
</fieldset>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsMMSPts" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:mmsptsConnectionString %>" 

SelectCommand="SELECT [Recommended], [PatientId] FROM [Patients] WHERE ([PatientId] = @PatientId)">
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtAcctNo" Name="PatientId" 
        PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I've seen examples where a SQl connection is established in codebehind.  Is that necessary, or does the above SQLDataSource take care of that?  Can anyone share some good links to creating message boxes based on query results?  In my case, if Recommended is 1 then messaage 1 would need to be show, if Reccommended is 2 then message 2 would need to be shown.  If the UserID is invalid, the third message needs to be shown.  How do I accomplish this?

UPDATE:
In my codebehind, I've written the following thus far:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
        ["mmsptsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        sqlconn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = connString;
        cmd.CommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter ("@PatientId", SQLDbType.varchar ));

        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
        {while reader.Read()
                    txtAcctNo.Text=cmd.Parameters("@PatientId")
        }

    }
```

My intent here is to call my stored procedure and return the results after binindg @PatientId to the txtAcctNo.Text.  I'm a bit rusty on the SqlClient stuff, what further steps are needed to get the results from my stored procedure?  One of the output parametsrs is @Recommended which is a bit field.  How would I evaluate the parameter value and trigger either a message box alert or a label control based on the value of this paramenter?  For example, if @Recommended = 1 then output "Message 1" to label1.text else output "Message 2" to lable1.text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do that work in the code-behind, whether you use the `SqlDataSource` or use `SqlConnection` directly is up to you.  But the `SqlDataSource` has no ability to directly interact with javascript or javascript libraries.

Comment: So, SQLDataSource can't be the "bridge" between the control and the database?  What JS library do you suggest for the message boxes?

Comment: The SqlDataSource can bridge between the database and the control, but it provides data to _server side_ code only, not client side code.  It sounds, based on your question that you want to initiate some kind of client side pop-up (i.e. `alert()` or maybe a jquery UI dialog).  It cannot provide data to those.

Comment: Not sure whether I want to use JS alert or just to output a label field on the page.  If I wanted to stick with server side controls, would I bind the results to the label or textbox so that it displays the desired message?  Do I create 3 hidden labels/textboxes one for each response?  If so, how do I display them based on query result?

Comment: You would still need to handle the logic in code-behind, the `SqlDataSource` is just as it name implies, it's a source of data.  It doesn't have any ability to execute logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `OnSelecting` event to modify the parameters:

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Command.Parameters["Arg1"].Value = TextBox1.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late response but for those who still look @ this

This is to show how to bind Texbox Value to the datasource and autorefresh it after modifying the textbox value

1. remove the selectpara and you don't need the code behind
2. just set AutoPostBack="True" to the textbox so when user type on it then exit from it ( or add a dummy search button in this case btnSubmit and set autopostback to true) it will fire and the datasource will refresh
3. modify the datasource selectcommand by removing the where clause of the patientid and add filter to it:

SelectCommand="SELECT [Recommended], [PatientId] FROM [Patients]"  FilterExpression="PatientId = '{0}'"

```
     <FilterParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="PatientId" ControlID="txtAcctNo" />
    </FilterParameters>
```